# Shift+Space does nothing Linux Mint

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint, and I'm having trouble with the Shift key. I'm not sure why, but when I press Space while I have it held down, it does nothing (I'd like it to type a space). Similarly, if I press Space when I have Caps Lock on, it does nothing.

Why is this? Is there some kind of computer shortcut I haven't found that is blocking Shift+Space (and Caps Lock space for whatever reason)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was causing the problem. Apparently, if you have the Hebrew (Biblical, Tiro) keyboard layout installed (you don't even need to be switched to it), it will mess up Shift+Space. I'm not sure why this happens, and I don't see it happening with any other keyboard layout (including the normal Hebrew keyboard layout).

Comment: Same by me! Thanks for posting! Is there a hope for workaround? Maybe the easiest is just to uninstall it and install whenever needed.